# Array remains empty after push

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I declared an array, But when I push elements inside it, it remains Empty. Here's my Code :

```
  var catsObjectId = new Array();
  var data = new Array();
  Recipe.find((err,doc3)=> {
    data = doc3;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      catsObjectId.push([]);
      data[i]['categories'].forEach((item, index) => {
        Recipecat.findOne({_id: item}, (err,result)=> {
          item = result.name;
          catsObjectId.push(item);
        });
      })
    }
    console.log(catsObjectId);
  });
```

> Here's the Recipe schema :

```
var recipeSchema = Schema({
  categories: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'RecipeCat',
  }]
});
```

> and Here's the Recipecat schema :

```
var recipecatSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

I want to replace objectIds for recipeCats with their names.

When I log 'catsObjectId', It shows an empty array.

What Seems to be the Problem?

Thanks In advance!

Comment: `.find()` and `.findOne()` are asynchronous

Comment: @Andreas How Should I Write the code?

Answer (score 9):

(I understand this question is a bit old, but if you still need help)

That's because you're pushing to an `array` which is outside the `callback` and the `async` nature of `JavaScript` kicking in.

Here's simple explanation why it's empty

```
var catsObjectId = new Array();
var data = new Array();

Recipe.find((err,doc3)=> {
  // say execution 1
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    catsObjectId.push([]);
    data[i]['categories'].forEach((item, index) => {
      // say execution 2
      Recipecat.findOne({_id: item}, (err,result)=> {
        item = result.name;
        catsObjectId.push(item);
      });
    })
  }
  // say execution 3
  console.log(catsObjectId);
});
```

First `execution 1` is executed. Within this `forEach` iterates over each item and fires `execution 2`. Then continues to execute `execution 3`.

The problem is `execution 2` is asynchronous and the value is returned sometime in the `future`. This future is after `excution 3` is executed. When `Recipecat.findOne` finishes execution, the `callback` within `then(result..` is called. But `console.log(catsObjectId)` is already executed and `catsObjectId` was empty at the time of execution.

You should either use `catsObjectId` within the callback `.then((data) => // use data here)` or use the `async/await` to make it `sync` like.

Note `await` is only valid inside `async` function

```
async function getSomeNames() {
  try {
    const data = await Recipe.find();
    // docs is an array of promises
    const docs = data.map((item, index) => {
      Recipecat.findOne({_id: item})
    });
    // items is an array of documents returned by findOne
    const items = await Promise.all(docs);
    // now you can map and get the names
    const names = items.map(item => item.name);
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    console.error(e);
  }
}
getSomeNames()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I had a similar case, and I had an async in the foreach and it returned empty, I followed the explanation and that was the solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your pushing an empty array every time it goes through the for loop. Try deleting this line.

```
catsObjectId.push([]);
```

Comment: Didn't Work, Still Empty !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use promises in order to control your code. Try the following code and tell me if an error exists.

```
Recipe.find().then(doc3 => {
    data = doc3;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i]['categories'].forEach((item, index) => {
        Recipecat.findOne({_id: item}).then(result => {
          item = result.name;
          catsObjectId.push(item);
        });
      })
    }
    console.log(catsObjectId);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Didn't Work, Still Empty !

Comment: Try to 'console.log' after each push to see what is happening. For example try this: catsObjectId.push(item); console.log(item); console.log(catsObjectId);

Comment: 'console.log' after push works just fine, But outside of it shows empty.

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran into a similar problem. Fix for me was to replace the `forEach` loop with a simple `for` loop. It turned out, that the `forEach` loop is not bothering about async-await, but the `for` loop is.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
let orders = await order_db.find({ profileID: req.body.id }).exec();
let final_orders = [];

for(let i=0; i<orders.length; i++){
    let order = orders[i];
    if (order.shopID != null) {
        let shop = await shop_db.find({ _id: order.shopID }).exec();
        let shopName = shop[0].name;
        let shopEmail = shop[0].email;
        let shopAddress = shop[0].address;
        let shopPhone = shop[0].phone;
        let updated_order = { ...order._doc, shopName, shopEmail, shopAddress, shopPhone };
        final_orders.push(updated_order);
    }
    else {
        let shopName = "";
        let shopEmail = "";
        let shopPhone = "";
        let shopAddress = "";
        let updated_order = { ...order._doc, shopName, shopEmail, shopAddress, shopPhone };
        final_orders.push(updated_order);
    }
};
```